# What does my teacher mean by 'choosing' from a vector?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

I'm revising some lecture notes from a class I missed, I'm just struggling to figure out what she means at this point. What is choosing x1=0, x2=1... etc mean? Could someone explain?

[image]

Comment: she means "setting", "letting", "specifying", or the like.

Comment: Every choice of values for $x_2$ and $x_3$ results in an eigenvector $\mathbf{x}$. Two of such choices are made, resulting in independent and convenient eigenvectors that span the whole set of eigenvectors.

Comment: I see now. Should I remove this?

Comment: For example, to evaluate $f(x,y) = x+2y$, you "choose" any values of $x$ and $y$ and plug them in: "choosing" $x=3$ and $y=7$ and you get $f(3,7)=17$.

Comment: @Rollo: wrt removing this, it's up to you, but you might also consider answering it yourself (this is [explicitly encouraged in the FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)) to help other people who might come across the same problem.